# Inverse multiplication axiom

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to define the inverse multiplication axiom.

Also known as:

```
∀x ∈ R\{0}  ∃y ∈ R  (x·y) = 1
```

And it needs to become this:

```
∀x ∈ R\{0}  ∃y ∈ R  x*x^{-1} = 1
```

How can I prove it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you asking how to prove that the $x^{-1}$ notation is well-defined, given the first axiom?

Comment: Um... If its an axiom you *don't* prove it.  You accept it as an axiom.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the question well :/ Yes, it is that! @ChrisCulter :)

Comment: Given that there is some $y$ such that $x\cdot y = 1$, then *we call $y$ the inverse of $x$ and choose to give $y$ the name and notation $x^{-1}$*.  This is a definition and does not need to be proven.  One can continue and prove that multiplicative inverses are unique using associativity of multiplication.

Comment: So what you need to prove is that there is only one such number.  That if $xy = 1$ and $xz = 1$ it *must* be true that $y=z$.  Thus we can define the notation that such a $y$ so that $xy$ will be denoted as $x^{-1}$.

Comment: But @JMoravitz we can not assume that so an inverse is unique.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for the help! I'm know understanding what I need to do!

Comment: @JMoravitz also thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By axiom, we are told and we take it as a given, that for every $x \ne 0; x\in R$ that that exist a $y$ so $xy = 1$.

What's left to prove is that such $y$ is unique.  i.e. If $xy = 1$ and $xz = 1$ then $y=z$.

Pf:  Let $xy = 1; xz = 1$.

Let $yd = 1$.  Then $x(yd)=x*1 = x$ and $(xy)d = 1*d = d$ so so $d = x$.  So $xy = yx = d$.

$yxz = y(xz)=y*1 = y$ and $yxz=(yx)z = 1*z = z$ so $y = z$

This not only proves that inverses are unique but if $y$ is a "left inverse" so that $xy = 1$ then $y$ is also a "right inverse" so that $yx = 1$.

In any event, such a $y$ so that $xy = 1$ is uniquely determined by each non-zero $x$ so we can distinctly define $x^{-1}$ as the unique and existing element so that $x*x^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much for the amazing help! :)